# Is there an easy way to calculate the probability of rolling a certain number or higher with multiple die.

Tags: probability, statistics

For example, assuming I have a 6 sided die, a 4 sided die, and 10 sided die. Is there a way to calculate the probability of rolling a total sum of 14 or higher?

I know I could manually add each combination to see if they are equal to or greater than 14, and then divide the number of outcomes which do by the total number of possible outcomes. But that is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 1):

For large number of die you could use the CLT (approximate the sum to a gaussian).

Here, you must compute that numerically.

With Octave or Matlab:

```
pa = ones(1,6)/6; % pmf of die A
pb = ones(1,4)/4; % pmf of die B
pc = ones(1,10)/10; % pmf of die C
pab = [0,conv(pa,pb)] % pmf of sum A,B
pabc = [0,conv(pab,pc)]; % pmf of sum A,B,C
sum(pabc(14:end)) % prob of sum being 14 or higher
```

This gives $0.30417$